# Different action on marker click android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on google  map android. I added some markers on map. I need to perform different action on different marker e.g one one marker click I just want to show info windowindow and on other marker click I want to open some activity. Please help how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

See [marker_click_events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events) from official docs:

> You can use an `OnMarkerClickListener` to listen for click events on
>   the marker. When a user clicks on a `marker`, `onMarkerClick(Marker)`
>   will be called and the marker will be passed through as an argument.
>   This method returns a boolean that indicates whether you have consumed
>   the event (i.e., you want to suppress the default behavior). If it
>   returns false, then the default behavior will occur in addition to
>   your custom behavior. The default behavior for a marker click event is
>   to show its info window (if available).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onMarkerClickListener` in agreement with [Google API v2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events).

You can implements the listener from your Activity (or Fragment) and then override `onMarkerClick(Marker)`

For example, your activty should be:

```
public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnMarkerClickListener{
        // ...
 }
```

Then, when you set up your map, you can do this:

```
yourMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); // yorMap is a GoogleMap object
```

Since you have implemented OnMarkerClickListner, you need to implement `onMarkerClick(Marker)`.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals(markerA)) {
        // action fired when markerA is clicked
    }else if(marker.equals(markerB)){
        // action fired when markerA is clicked
    }
    return false;
}
```

where markerA and markerB are two `Marker` objects:

```
private Marker markerA;
private Marker markerB;
```

that it is supposed to be added before, for example in this way:

```
markerA = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(LatA, LonA))
            .title("marker A"));

// the same for markerB
```

Comment: But to differentiate which marker is clicked. This event will be added to all markers on map